# Experimental implications of unitarity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

I have two questions with regards to unitarity:

1. To which extent it has been verified experimentally that quantum systems evolve in a unitary way when dealing with unbounded Hamiltonians?
2. Let us define an operator $\mathcal{\hat{N}}(t,\,t_{0})\,\equiv\,\sqrt{\hat{U}^{\dagger}(t,\,t_{0})\,\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})}$ where $\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\,=\,\hat{T}\exp\left[-i\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{\prime}\,\hat{H}(t^{\prime})\right]$.
   According to the current understanding, the action of such an operator should not affect anything as the unitarity of $\hat{U}$ implies $\mathcal{\hat{N}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{1}}$.
   Suppose that I would like to check this assumption experimentally. How can one verify if the action of such an operator is indeed trivial (or not)?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/804783/2451

Comment: Hi Yair. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.